# Why chrome does not prompt for NTLM credentials on Linux when only "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate" is sent? On Windows it does

Tags: linux, windows, google-chrome, ntlm, http-negotiate

I have a server that supports both methods Negotiate & NTLM (Using [Waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle)). The detail is that it only sends "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate".
On Windows, this works as expected: Chrome prompts for NTLM credentials. But on Linux, this fails without prompting for any credentials.
I know that this works if I explicitly send another header "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM", but my question is: what is the difference in Chrome between Windows & Linux, that Windows "seems" to detect that the server supports NTLM without the extra header?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses the OS library to negotiate the authentication. On Linux this is typically GSS-API, which doesn't correctly negotiate fallback to NTLM.

You can resolve the issue on your Linux machine by installing https://github.com/gssapi/gss-ntlmssp